# SQL Query which join two tables and display Total amount of invoice number

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am new at Stackoverflow, sorry for my poor english, and please do not give negative marks on my question, I really need ans for this.

I have been working on one assignment. I have two tables **sale_head** and **sale_details**

Table sale_head has following fields. **-- invoiceno (PK),suppliername,invoicedate**
and Table sale_details has following fields. **-- invoiceno(FK),suppliername,product_code,qty,totalkg,rate,subtotal**

Basically What I have done here is, i have two tables master and slave, master table has all head information of the data and details tables has rest of the details like product code, product quantity, rate, and total etc.

So far I have come up with one SQL query which is below

```
SELECT sale_head.suppliername AS sale_head_suppliername,
       sale_head.invoiceno AS sale_head_invoiceno, sale_head.invoicedate,
       sale_details.invoiceno AS sale_details_invoiceno,
       sale_details.suppliername AS sale_details_suppliername, 
       sale_details.product_code, sale_details.qty, sale_details.totalkg,
       sale_details.Rate, sale_details.subtotal 
       FROM sale_head 
       INNER JOIN sale_details ON sale_head.[invoiceno] = sale_details.[invoiceno]
       WHERE (((sale_head.suppliername)='Ramkrishna Creation'));
```

Above query display some certain result(date have been displayed in high amount so) please refer this image link. which will show you results of above SQL query
The Result I have come up : [Image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5xs69-03ZA_enQzckNWbGo4MDA/edit?usp=sharing)

What **result** I want to display is : [Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5xs69-03ZA_VDdieG96REZoS3c/edit?usp=sharing)
I want Sum of Subtotal at end of the invoice number as I have shown in above result image, Do not get attend on colors, I have just displayed color you draw your attention.
I really need answer for this so help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `UNION ALL` as:

```
SELECT sale_head.suppliername AS sale_head_suppliername,
sale_head.invoiceno AS sale_head_invoiceno, sale_head.invoicedate,
sale_details.invoiceno AS sale_details_invoiceno, sale_details.suppliername AS       sale_details_suppliername,
sale_details.product_code, sale_details.qty, sale_details.totalkg, sale_details.Rate,   sale_details.subtotal FROM sale_head 

INNER JOIN sale_details ON sale_head.[invoiceno] = sale_details.[invoiceno] 
UNION ALL
select 'Total', sum(sale_details.subtotal) from sale_details

WHERE (((sale_head.suppliername)='Ramkrishna Creation'));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, When i try to run this SQL in MsAccess, it give me an error called "Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression 'sum(sale_details.subtotal)"
WHERE (((sale_head.suppliername)='Ramkrishna Creation'))'

What could be the solution ?

Comment: Thanks But now it says that **The number of columns in the two selected tables or query of a union query do not match.**